# How would you convert these two Swift enums to Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

**NOTE:** The Swift code is not mine. I am just converting it to Objective-C as a challenge :D

---

**QUESTION:** How would you convert both these enums below to Objective-C?

```
public enum ISO8601Format: String {

    case Year = "yyyy" // 1997
    case YearMonth = "yyyy-MM" // 1997-07
    case Date = "yyyy-MM-dd" // 1997-07-16
    case DateTime = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ" // 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
    case DateTimeSec = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" // 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
    case DateTimeMilliSec = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" // 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00

    init(dateString:String) {
        switch dateString.characters.count {
        case 4:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.Year.rawValue)!
        case 7:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.YearMonth.rawValue)!
        case 10:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.Date.rawValue)!
        case 22:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.DateTime.rawValue)!
        case 25:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.DateTimeSec.rawValue)!
        default:// 28:
            self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.DateTimeMilliSec.rawValue)!
        }
    }
}

public enum DateFormat {
    case ISO8601(ISO8601Format?), DotNet, RSS, AltRSS, Custom(String)
}
```

---

**WHAT I TRIED:**

#### Dateformat.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString * const ISO8601DateFormatType;
extern NSString * const DotNetDateFormatType;
extern NSString * const RSSDateFormatType;
extern NSString * const AltRSSDateFormatType;
extern NSString * const CustomDateFormatType;

extern NSString * const ISOFormatYear;
extern NSString * const ISOFormatYearMonth; // 1997-07
extern NSString * const ISOFormatDate; // 1997-07-16
extern NSString * const ISOFormatDateTime; // 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
extern NSString * const ISOFormatDateTimeSec; // 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
extern NSString * const ISOFormatDateTimeMilliSec; // 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00


@interface DateFormat : NSObject

+ (instancetype) ISODateFormat: (NSString *) isoFormat;
+ (instancetype) DotNetDateFormat;
+ (instancetype) RSSDateFormat;
+ (instancetype) AltRSSDateFormat;
+ (instancetype) CustomDateFormat: (NSString *) formatString;

@property (readonly) NSString *dateFormatType;
@property (readonly) NSString *formatDetails;


@end
```

#### DateFormat.m

```
#import "DateFormat.h"

@implementation DateFormat

NSString * const ISO8601DateFormatType = @"ISO8601";
NSString * const DotNetDateFormatType = @"DotNet";
NSString * const RSSDateFormatType = @"RSS";
NSString * const AltRSSDateFormatType = @"AltRSS";
NSString * const CustomDateFormatType = @"Custom";

NSString * const ISOFormatYear = @"yyyy";
NSString * const ISOFormatYearMonth = @"yyyy-MM"; // 1997-07
NSString * const ISOFormatDate = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; // 1997-07-16
NSString * const ISOFormatDateTime = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"; // 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
NSString * const ISOFormatDateTimeSec = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"; // 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
NSString * const ISOFormatDateTimeMilliSec = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"; // 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00

- (instancetype) initWithType: (NSString *) formatType details: (NSString *) details {

    if(self = [super init]) {
        _dateFormatType = formatType;
        _formatDetails = details;
    }

    return self;
}

+ (instancetype) ISODateFormat: (NSString *) isoFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: ISO8601DateFormatType details: isoFormat];
}

+ (instancetype) DotNetDateFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: DotNetDateFormatType details: nil];
}

+ (instancetype) RSSDateFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: RSSDateFormatType details: nil];
}

+ (instancetype) AltRSSDateFormat
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: AltRSSDateFormatType details: nil];
}

+ (instancetype) CustomDateFormat: (NSString *) formatString
{
    return [[DateFormat alloc] initWithType: CustomDateFormatType details: formatString];
}

@end
```

Comment: `self = ISO8601Format(rawValue: ISO8601Format.Year.rawValue)!` absolutely makes no sense. It's exactly the same as `self = Year`.

Comment: That's the swift code I am converting from (not my code). It's an exercise I am doing to learn Objective-C.

Comment: You don't even need the `init(dateString:)`, the default initializer `init(rawValue:)` does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: As I said, it's not my code. I just want to convert this to Objective-C. I already converted 1.5k lines of code, but I am blocking on this.

Comment: It's great to let us know that "I tried this", but you are absolutely lacking the part where ***you tell us why it isn't working***.  This includes build errors, runtime errors, and/or a description from you saying what you expected to happen and what actually did happen.  Keep this in mind for your next question!  And if you edit that info into this one you might get rid of some more of those downvotes.

Comment: @Will I edited my question ! I hope it's better and clearer now !

Comment: @TimVermeulen I edited my question ! I hope it's better and clearer now !

Comment: @Coder1000 Reread my comment. Your code is overly complicated, you don't have to use those `rawValue`s like that.

Comment: @TimVermeulen  It's not my code. It's some swift code I found that I am converting as a challenge ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on the Objective-C side so there may be easier ways to code this. It's all done in Swift code which gets bridged over to Objective-C:

```
import Foundation

/// enum ISO8601Format String for Swift
public enum ISO8601Format: String {
  case Year             = "yyyy"                       // 1997
  case YearMonth        = "yyyy-MM"                    // 1997-07
  case Date             = "yyyy-MM-dd"                 // 1997-07-16
  case DateTime         = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"        // 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
  case DateTimeSec      = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"     // 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
  case DateTimeMilliSec = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" // 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00
}

/// Bridges ISO8601Format to class constants for Objective-C
@objc(ISO8601Format)
class ISO8601FormatBridge: NSObject {
  static let Year             = ISO8601Format.Year.rawValue
  static let YearMonth        = ISO8601Format.YearMonth.rawValue
  static let Date             = ISO8601Format.Date.rawValue
  static let DateTime         = ISO8601Format.DateTime.rawValue
  static let DateTimeSec      = ISO8601Format.DateTimeSec.rawValue
  static let DateTimeMilliSec = ISO8601Format.DateTimeMilliSec.rawValue
}

/// enum DateFormat for Swift
public enum DateFormat {
  case ISO8601(ISO8601Format?)
  case DotNet
  case RSS
  case AltRSS
  case Custom(String)

  /// Strings for each case
  var name: String {
    switch self {
    case ISO8601 : return "ISO8601"
    case DotNet  : return "DotNet"
    case RSS     : return "RSS"
    case AltRSS  : return "AltRSS"
    case Custom  : return "Custom"
    }
  }
}

/// Bridges DateFormat to class factory methods for Objective-C
@objc(DateFormat)
class DateFormatBridge: NSObject {
  class func ISO8601(details:String?) -> DateFormatBridge {
    return DateFormatBridge(DateFormat.ISO8601(nil).name, details: details)
  }

  class func DotNet() -> DateFormatBridge {
    return DateFormatBridge(DateFormat.DotNet.name, details: nil)
  }

  class func RSS() -> DateFormatBridge {
    return DateFormatBridge(DateFormat.RSS.name, details: nil)
  }

  class func AltRSS() -> DateFormatBridge {
    return DateFormatBridge(DateFormat.AltRSS.name, details: nil)
  }

  class func Custom(details: String) -> DateFormatBridge {
    return DateFormatBridge(DateFormat.Custom("").name, details: details)
  }

  /// Type of Swift enum DateFormat
  let type: String
  /// Associated value of the type
  let details: String?

  /// Create instances with associated values
  private init(_ format: String, details: String?) {
    self.type = format
    self.details = details
  }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [ISO8601Format Year]);       // => "yyyy"
NSLog(@"%@", [ISO8601Format YearMonth]);  // => "yyyy-MM"

DateFormat * date = [DateFormat ISO8601:[ISO8601Format Year]];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", [date type], [date details]); // => "ISO8601, yyyy"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it actually fits perfectly my question now :D